Templates `xctemplate` is missing Xcode 16
I update my Xcode to version 16 then the my custom templates are not displayed any more.
I can see them under /Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File\ Templates but it is not displayed when I want to create a new file from template.
What am I missing ? is there any changes for Xcode 16?

Hmm, I can see mine and I haven't done anything related to templates after upgrading to Xcode 16.
